# Dans la phrase "je ne trouve plus les miennes", quel est le sens de 'plus'?

Tags: grammaire

Je pense que on utilise plus' pour donner le sensé imperfectif de l'action, mais je suis débutant en français et je n'ai pas la certitude, pouvez-vous m'expliquer? S'il-vous plaît.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL. Que signifie « sensé imperfectif » ?

Answer (score 4):

« Plus » est le deuxième composant de la négation « ne plus ».

Contrairement à « ne pas » qui indique une négation simple, « ne plus » indique que la proposition était vraie dans le passé, mais qu'elle ne l'est pas en ce moment, c'est à dire qu'elle ne l'est « plus ».

En anglais, ce « ne plus » se rend par *not anymore* ou *no more*.

Comment: `mais qu'elle ne l'est pas en ce moment` pourrait être remplacé par `mais qu'elle ne l'est pas désormais`, qui fixe le point dans le temps à partir duquel la proposition est invalidée. En d'autres termes, `en ce moment` indique "un état temporaire réversible" alors que quand `elles seront retrouvées`, leur perte actuelle sera toujours présente dans l'idée de **`retrouvées`**.