# “n'ai pas” vs “n’ai plus”

Tags: grammaire

“I have no money” could be either

> Je n'ai pas d'argent.

Or

> Je n'ai plus d'argent.

I wonder, is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Je n'ai pas d'argent

means you have no money. Maybe you had some money before, maybe you have never had any money - but right now, you have no money.

> Je n'ai plus d'argent

means you have no money left: in the past, you had some money, but now you have spent it or you have lost it, and you have no more money now.

Comment: Good answer, but we should prefer to find duplicates for such questions if we can. Otherwise we will never stop answering questions about n'ai pas vs. n'ai plus, n'a pas vs. n'a plus, n'avons pas vs. n'avons plus, n'est pas vs. n'est plus, n'êtes pas vs. n'êtes plus ... you get the idea. We have questions about negative adverbs, such as [1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24556/24557), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24665/24678), [3](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25268/25273).

Answer (score 2):

« je n'ai plus d'argent » sous-tend que j'en avais auparavant alors que « je n'ai pas d'argent » peut vouloir dire que je n'en ai jamais eu.